# React JS - Tick Callback passing object argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, scatter

I have a scatter graph and a callback function calling mapValtoString to define the tick value of the x axis. I need to pass dendoLabels to that function which will be the "liste" argument of the function.

In the code below, datas and dendolabels are empty to make it easier to read.

When I try to pass dendolabels to the function, it pass an undefined object. I absolutely don't understand why it can't reach it.

```js
function mapValtoString(val,liste){

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(liste).length ; i++) {
      if (liste[i]["x"] == val) {
        return liste[i]["label"]
      }

    }
        return val
};


class Dashboard extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    bigChartData: "data1",
    dendo: [],

 };
};

dendoLabels =  [{x:"5", label:"Test"}]
chartExample3 = {
data: canvas => {
  let datass = []
  console.log(this.dendoLabels)
  for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(this.state.dendo).length; i++) {
    if (this.state.dendo[i]["Label1"] != "") {this.dendoLabels.push({x:this.state.dendo[i]["x1"], label: this.state.dendo[i]["Label1"]})}        
    if (this.state.dendo[i]["Label2"] != "") {this.dendoLabels.push({x:this.state.dendo[i]["x3"], label: this.state.dendo[i]["Label2"]})}

      datass.push({
        borderColor: "#d048b6",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        showLine: true,
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        data:[{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x1"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y1"], index:this.state.dendo[i]["Label1"]},{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x2"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y2"]}]},

        {
        borderColor: "#d048b6",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        showLine: true,
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        data:[{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x3"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y3"]},{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x4"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y4"]}]},

        {
        borderColor: "#d048b6",
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderDash: [],
        showLine: true,
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        data:[{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x2"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y2"]},{x: this.state.dendo[i]["x3"],y: this.state.dendo[i]["y3"], index:this.state.dendo[i]["Label2"]}]
      })
  }
   return{
    datasets: datass,
  }
},

options: {
  legend: false,
  fontSize: 30,
  color: "#666",
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: true,
                stepSize: 5,
                callback: function(value,index,values){
                      console.log(this.dendoLabels)
                      return mapValtoString(value,this.dendoLabels)
                  },

            }
        }]
    }
}
```

};

dendoLabels is in the format of the code below which is working by the way, you will find the result in the image below.

```js
ticks: {
 display: true,
 stepSize: 5,
 callback: function(value,index,values, dendoLabels = [{x:"5", label:"It works"}]){
 return mapValtoString(value,dendoLabels)
 },
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmkGd.png)

How can I pass my dendoLabel object to that function ?

Comment: Where does `ticks.callback()` get invoked?

Comment: It is called automatically when the graph is rendered

Answer (score 0):

The following code "works" because `dendoLabels` is not passed to the callback when it's invoked and the default value is used instead.

```
ticks: {
 display: true,
 stepSize: 5,
 callback: function(value,index,values, dendoLabels = [{x:"5", label:"It works"}]){
 return mapValtoString(value,dendoLabels)
 },
}
```

The problem is that the `dendoLabels` variable in living inside the chartExample3.data() scope and out of the callback's reach. The solution is to use a closure.

First, remove the `dendoLabels` from the callback's arguments.

```
callback: function(value,index,values)
```

Now define `dendoLabels` as a variable in the same scope that `chartExample3` currently lives in.

Like this.

```
let dendoLabels = [{x:"5", label:"It works"}]

chartExample3 = {
  data: canvas => {
  let datas = []
  return{
    datasets: datas,
  }
},
options: {
  legend: false,
  fontSize: 30,
  color: "#666",
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: true,
                stepSize: 5,
                callback: function(value,index,values){
                return mapValtoString(value,dendoLabels)
                },
            }
        }]
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT because of new requirement**. Setting dendoLabels as a property of React component.

If you want to use `this.dendoLabels` you must add it as a property of that class and you must assure that the callback is invoked within the right context. It isn't clear from the code that you posted what is and isn't part of the class and how the callback is invoked.

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      bigChartData: "data1"
      , dendo: []
    }
  }

  dendoLabels = [{
    x: "5"
    , label: "Test"
  }]
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue even in this context. I updated my code in my post

Comment: Why are you prefix the variable with `this`? `this.dendoLabels` won't work because it's not property of the React component and it's part of a different context. Did you try what I posted?

Comment: Everything is part of the react component. The problem with your solution is that it has to be defined outside of the class but I want it to be part of it

Answer (score 0):

Try using an arrow function `() => {}` rather than `function() {}`.

You can read more on the difference between them [here](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/es5-functions-vs-es6-fat-arrow-functions-864033baa1a).